# How to gvfs-mount a CD as non-root user?

Tags: linux, mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gvfs

I can mount a CD like this:

```
sudo dbus-launch gvfs-mount cdda://sr0
```

And I get the tracks as .wav files in `/root/.gvfs`.

But it mounts as root, and `chown` doesn't work (not implemented in the fuse driver I guess).  If I try running this commands as a non-root user, it doesn't work.

The output from `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-fuse-daemon --help` has lines indicating `-o uid=$UID` and `-o gid=$GID` exist, but I can't figure out how to use them.  I'm not manually starting the daemon and I can't figure out where that happens.  Whe n I tried manually starting the daemon it caused other problems, and adding -o options doesn't seem to work (to the daemon or the `gvfs-mount` command).

Does anyone know what the syntax of this is supposed to be, or can anyone offer other help as to what I might be doing wrong?

(OS is Raspbian on a Pi 2, so basically Debian Wheezy).

Comment: Check this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/4140/349837) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483460/how-to-mount-from-command-line-like-the-nautilus-does).